# How to delete everything between two characters on each line of input?

Tags: bash, unix

Hi I have a problem as I want to delete by sed or maybe by another command all between space and c

```
85.89.161.147 [11/cdlinux-0.5.8.iso
```

so I want to leave 85.89.161.147 cdlinux-0... I've tried other people tips but none of them have worked for me. Any ideas? I would also ask you to explain why this way as I'm studying Linux now so it would help me a lot:)

Comment: _I've tried other people tips but none of them have worked for me. Any ideas?_ - what have you tried so far? This will help to not give you duplicate adivce

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: well man, my task is to count the versions of linux downloaded I've already done it the other way but good results vary a little bit so I'm searching for a better result. I have no clue how should it be correctly done

Comment: so in my case i have thousands of the same lines as in my question and i have to count them using uniq -c but firstly i have to uniq duplicated downloads the same version from the same ip so i have to leave it as I asked in the question := )

Comment: i've already tried sed -n '/Here/,/String/p' but instead of here and string i used space and c

Comment: then tried something like this "Hello world xxx this is a file yyy" | sed 's/.*xxx \(.*\)yyy/\1/' but I have no clue how it works so I would be pleasant if somebody gave me an answer and explain a little bit

Comment: If you want my code, cat cdlinux.www.log | grep " 200" | cut -d "/" -f 1,8 | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sort -u | grep "\.iso" | cut -d "H" -f 1 | cut -d " " -f 1,4  this is my code so far but it surely wouldn't help you answering my question

Comment: `sed 's/\[[[:digit:]]\+\///'` hope this helps

Comment: okay, then can you help me understand this line? step by step please?

Comment: `s` is substitute command. now regex is as follows: `\[` is bracket escaped, `[[:digit:]]\+` matches all the numbers, `\/` is forward slash escaped and finally `//` is substitute with empty string :)

Comment: thank you very much ! It worked for me

Comment: Going forward, try to focus your questions on the thing you're trying to accomplish, not the tools you imagine the person answering might choose to use for the job. Sometimes `sed` is the right tool for the job, but sometimes it's better to use `awk`, or `grep`, or even bash's built-in regex support.

Comment: That question lacks the context. For example, what should be done of `a dc xc`? Should the output be `a c xc` or `a c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps

```
sed 's/\[[[:digit:]]\+\///'
```

`s` is substitute command. now regex is as follows: `\[` is bracket escaped, `[[:digit:]]\+` matches all the numbers, `\/` is forward slash escaped and finally `//` is substitute with empty string :)

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before". (Likewise the bullet point about questions that don't identify a specific problem; ideally, the OP would have showed what they tried, and exactly how it failed).